# Bubble fire event in svg.js

Tags: svg, svg.js

I have this structure:

```
 ___________________
| g1 __________     |
|   | g2       |    | 
|   |          |    |
|   |   ____   |    |
|   |  | r1 |  |    |
|   |  |____|  |
|   |__________|    |
|___________________|
```

Only the object on which `fire` is called receives the event.

```
r1.fire('myevent')
r1.on('myevent',doSomething) //works
g2.on('myevent',doSomething) //not called
g1.on('myevent',doSomething) //not called
```

How can I trigger a `fire` on a child element and have all parents receive the event?

Stack Snippet:

```js
var canvas = SVG().addTo("body");
var g1 = canvas.group();
var g2 = g1.group(); //inside group1
var r1 = g2.rect(100, 100).fill("blue"); //inside group2

g1.on("customEvent", function (e) {
    console.log("Custom event captured by group1");
});

g2.on("customEvent", function (e) {
    console.log("event fired");
    //this.parent().fire("customEvent");// this shouldn't be needed
});

// Trigger the custom event on rectangle2, manually propagate it up to both group1 and group2
r1.on("click", function () {
    this.parent().fire("customEvent");
    //this.parent().fire("customEvent");// this shouldn't be needed
});
r1.on("customEvent", function () {
    console.log("event fired");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.2.0/svg.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you update the question with the code that creates the simple nested boxes you're using and provides the `r1`, `g1`, and `g2` variables? (You can even make it runnable using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/), just use the "Add External Library" button to add `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js` and use its global `SVG` object.) (But just the code is fine too, provided it's self-contained. It's basic, I know, but it would help to answer your question.)

Comment: added the full code. firing event on rect is not listened upwards unless you explicitly call parent.fire which defeats the purpose of events.

Comment: I've updated the names in the "full code" to match the names you gave originally. The full code still doesn't match the short version of the code you provided. (Those kinds of inconsistencies make it difficult to answer questions.) But it sure looks like svg.js is getting in your way here rather than helping. :-|

Comment: While this was a slight disappointment, but the library is adorable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

svg.js uses CustomEvents under the hood and you can pass options as third parameter to the `fire` method:

```js
element.fire('eventname', someData, { bubbles: true })
```

This is public api but I realized its extremely hidden in the docs under:
https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.1/events/#custom-events

```js
const canvas = SVG().addTo("body");
const g1 = canvas.group();
const g2 = g1.group();
const r1 = g2.rect(100, 100).fill("blue");

g1.on("custom-event", (e) => {
    console.log(`g1 saw ${e.type}: ${e.detail.answer}`);
});
g2.on("custom-event", (e) => {
    console.log(`g2 saw ${e.type}: ${e.detail.answer}`);
});
r1.on("custom-event", (e) => {
    console.log(`r1 saw ${e.type}: ${e.detail.answer}`);
});
r1.on("click", (e) => {
    r1.fire("custom-event", {answer: 42}, {bubbles: true});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.2.0/svg.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"This is public api but I realized its extremely hidden in the docs..."* It is indeed. :-) [Here](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.1/events/#element-fire) would be a good place for it. I looked there, I searched for "bubbles" [anywhere in the docs](https://duckduckgo.com/?q="bubbles"+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fsvgjs.dev) (didn't think to search for "cancelable"). But at least the feature is there!

Comment: true, guess I need to update the docs... :D

Answer (score 2):

Kicking around the svg.js documentation and experimenting a fair bit, I'm not finding a way to make its custom events bubble.

<s>If you don't get a pure svg.js-based solution</s> *(Fuzzma has [provided one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77371740/157247) now)* you could use [DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) on the underlying SVG elements it creates (accessed via the `.node` property on the svg.js objects):

```js
const canvas = SVG().addTo("body");
const g1 = canvas.group();
const g2 = g1.group();
const r1 = g2.rect(100, 100).fill("blue");

g1.node.addEventListener("custom-event", (e) => {
    console.log(`g1 saw ${e.type}: ${e.detail.answer}`);
});
g2.node.addEventListener("custom-event", (e) => {
    console.log(`g2 saw ${e.type}: ${e.detail.answer}`);
});
r1.node.addEventListener("custom-event", (e) => {
    console.log(`r1 saw ${e.type}: ${e.detail.answer}`);
});
r1.node.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // Respond to click by raising a custom event that bubbles
    const customEvent = new CustomEvent("custom-event", {
        bubbles: true,
        detail: {answer: 42} // (If you want custom detail)
    });
    r1.node.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.2.0/svg.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great. If I don't get a native svg way, I will mark it as answer.